# Falling through a switch case?

Tags: php, javascript

I was in the process of writing a switch case when I read on the PHP site:

`Thus, it is important not to forget break statements (even though you may want to avoid supplying them on purpose under certain circumstances).`

A switch case without break statements was perfect for what I wanted to do. I want all the cases below the matched one to execute. Why is this wrong, and what is the best way to do it differently?

Is it bad for all languages, or just PHP? Why?

edit: Whether it is or isn't a problem, is there a way to do the same thing without a switch case?

Comment: It sounds like your use case falls into the "you may want to avoid supplying them on purpose under certain circumstances" clause.

Comment: @Gabe: Yes, yes it does.

Comment: If your know exactly your switch works, then no wrong in doing so. Its just a warning, some times developers forget to put break and thus they bang heads later for incorrect outputs.

Comment: Why does it say not to forget them, even if you don't want to use them, though?

Comment: Its a thumbs up. Many times i have have forgotten to put break and banged head later, but not too late 2 pull my hair off though :)

Comment: @user828584 - remembering about break isn't the same as _using_ break. Any time you write a switch statement you should keep breaks in mind, but that doesn't mean you have to match them one-for-one with your cases. Also, not sure about PHP, but in JavaScript (and several other languages) it is also legit to use return statements rather than break if that suits your purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it noted -  *even though you may want to avoid supplying them on purpose under certain circumstances*. As long as you know what you are doing, then falling through case is not a problem. Personally, I think that it's a large reason why using case statements can be so useful (instead of &&'s, but that's just me).

So the answer is, it's not bad for any particular language, because you aren't fighting with the language.

Comment: It's pretty bad for C#, since it's a compiler error to do so.

Comment: Falling through case statements?

Comment: @dlev: Thanks, I was wondering if it would be different between languages. I've seen some c++ examples with it though. Are you sure that you can't in C#?

Comment: Yep. "Control cannot fall through from one case label to another". You can *group* them together, but if there's code, you need a `break;`

Comment: So how would you write the equivalent?

Comment: @dlev - Oh, I misread the question. I'm not sure if user828584 is talking about falling through switches or breaks, because I (accidentally) use them interchangeably too. I see no use of falling through switches.

Comment: In my opinion not being allowed to fall through when there is code is the most obnoxious feature of the C# language. Fall-throughs are for me to decide and on my head if I get it wrong, not for the language designers to forbid outright. (I'm annoyed about this because it was only this morning that I _wanted_ to do it, and in context it would've made the code _much_ more logical and easy to read than the series of if statements I was forced into.)

Answer (score 0):

Opinions on switch statement fall-through execution generally mirrors opinions regarding goto.

Switch is intended to be mutually exclusive, but can be gotten around (in c# anyway) by using the goto keyword.  Since PHP added the goto keyword, you can probably do something similar.  An example from MSFT is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Y200) in the switch documentation.

Personally, I find it much clearer to be explicit regarding the code I need to execute which is intended to be mutually exclusive.  I find that I add/remove cases to switch statements and thus have the added headache of making sure they are ordered correctly when using a language which allows for fall-through execution.

Comment: I don't like (and never have a need for) `goto`, but I like fall-throughs _when clearer than an equivalent series of if tests_. As a matter of form I always put a comment `//fall through` where the `break;` would've been to make it clear that it's on purpose. Couldn't C# (or any other language that forbids it) have included a `fallthrough` keyword so that the functionality was still available but couldn't happen by mistake? (OK, I suppose a copy/paste re-ordering could still break it, but that applies to if/else alternatives too, so...)

Comment: goto has always been controversial, but I've sympathized with programmers who have used it to break out of deeply nested loops for the same purpose that you state: clarity.  Sometimes it's much clearer than a bunch of nested if/break combinations.

The distinction made is that C# tries to enforce the mutual exclusivity of the branching, whereas the C/C++ versions are essentially syntactic sugar over goto statements where the logical tests are located closer to the goto label.

This is also why switch can be completely replicated with if/elseif/else statements in C#, but not in C/C++.

Answer (score -1):

In one word: **RESOURCES**

If you use the **IF** construct the interpreter will go over every possibility in order to find if it's **TRUE** or **FALSE**, this **WASTES RESOURCES**, **Memory** and **CPU**.
The all point of using the **SWITCH** statement with **BREAK** is to **SPARE RESOURCES**, because when a matching condition is found the interpreter will **BREAK** and won't try to find any more matches.

What you're doing can be easily accomplished with the **IF**, **ELSE** or **ELSEIF** constructs rather than with the **SWITCH** statement, if you don't mind wasting resources, of course.

Comment: Actually, no.  Fall through execution cannot be easily accomplished with if/else/elseif.

In addition, the syntactic change in C# in other languages was added to make it harder to write buggy code (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Disadvantages) older languages (e.g. C, C++) allowed fall through, and considering that a break probably boils down to adding/omitting a jump, resources aren't really a consideration either.

Comment: I failed to mention that I was referring to php language.